# Get Search Results Number Using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup in Python to get the total number of search results in CNN.

The source code on the webpage is

```
<div class="cnn-search__results-count">

"Displaying results 1-10 out of 2208 for"

<strong>toronto</strong>

</div>
```

as shown in screenshot 1:

[image: Screenshot 1]

The code I wrote is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url_cnn = 'https://www.cnn.com/search?q=toronto'

response_cnn = requests.get(url_cnn)

html_cnn = response_cnn.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_cnn, 'html.parser')

cnn = (soup.find('div', {"class": "cnn-search__results-count"}))

print(cnn)
```

However, I only get

```
<div class="cnn-search__results-count"></div>
```

All the contents in between are missing.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm advising to add a internet and websites related tags. A knowledge in python and beautifulsoup might not be enough.

Comment: Thanks Yonlif! I added some new tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website is loaded with `JavaScript` event which render it's data dynamically once the page loads.

`requests` library will not be able to render `JavaScript` on the fly. so you can use `selenium` or `requests_html`. and indeed there's a lot of modules which can do that.

Now, we do have another option on the table, to track from where the data is rendered. I were able to locate the [XHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) request which is used to retrieve the data from the `back-end` `API` and render it to the users side.

> You can get the `XHR` request by open [Developer-Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and check [Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) and check `XHR/JS` requests made depending of the type of call such as `fetch`

```py
import requests
import json


r = requests.get("https://search.api.cnn.io/content?q=toronto&size=10").json()

data = json.dumps(r, indent=4)

# print(data) #to see the full output in nice format.

# print(r.keys()) # to see the keys of the JSON dict

print(r["meta"])
```

Output:

```
{'start': 1, 'end': 10, 'total': 10, 'of': 2208, 'maxScore': None, 'duration': 
55}
```

> Note: you can play with `q=toronto` to query another `keyword`, and `size=10` to define the size of output.